# Wrong certificate used for every website

Tags: ssl, certificate, wget, curl, ubuntu-16.04

On an Ubuntu 16.04 host, using cURL or Wget on any website results in the following error:

```
% sudo wget https://github.com --debug
DEBUG output created by Wget 1.17.1 on linux-gnu.

Reading HSTS entries from /home/perlwle/.wget-hsts
URI encoding = ‘UTF-8’
--2020-06-03 17:06:22--  https://github.com/
Resolving github.com (github.com)... 13.250.177.223
Caching github.com => 13.250.177.223
Connecting to github.com (github.com)|13.250.177.223|:443... connected.
Created socket 3.
Releasing 0x000055bd8d06ab10 (new refcount 1).
Initiating SSL handshake.
Handshake successful; connected socket 3 to SSL handle 0x000055bd8d06b400
certificate:
  subject: CN=*.example.com
  issuer:  CN=RapidSSL RSA CA 2018,OU=www.digicert.com,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US
ERROR: no certificate subject alternative name matches
        requested host name ‘github.com’.
To connect to github.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
Closed 3/SSL 0x000055bd8d06b400
```

The problem is at the `subject: CN=*.example.com`, with `example.com` being an example. It's a domain I have purchased with the setup certificate, on another host. To give more context, it's an LXC host running inside the current one.

I am baffled why the wrong certification is used and I am not sure where to look for help.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23231788/ssl-error-certificate-subject-name-does-not-match-target-host-for-github-com

Comment: Do you have any iptables or nftables NAT rules, either inside lxc or outside? Specifically look for "DNAT" or "REDIRECT".

Comment: @Steve I have come cross this link and tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: @user1686  You are on the right track.  I started looking into iptables settings right after my post. Lo and behold  `-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to 192.168.192.47:443`  commented it out and it works now. Would you like to post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are always getting *your own* certificate, that usually means there is a stray iptables NAT rule which redirects all traffic to your own server.

Check `iptables-save` and specifically look for `-j DNAT` and `-j REDIRECT` rules.